# How can I remove entries from Google Chrome browsing history by keyword?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want to remove my history from Google Chrome by keyword, for example "youtube", or "wikipedia". I've only been able to find plugins which remove all history based on time, e.g. 3 days ago.

Using `chrome://history/` doesn't allow me to select all, from a search, only individually.

[image: screenshot of Google Chrome history tab]

Answer (score 1):

You can still search for history with the keyword using `chrome://history`.

Just search for history with the keyword then press `Ctrl + A`, which will select the entire list and delete.